# Mouseenter and Mouseleave to trigger timer on/off

Tags: jquery, reload, mouseenter, mouseleave, idle-timer

How would I code a **mouseenter event to trigger timer off and a mouseleave event to trigger the timer on**?

If the timer interval is reached then webpage will refresh.

I've tried to do it but couldn't work it out:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var timer;
        function start() {
            timer = setInterval(function(){refresh()}, 5000);
        }
        start();
        $('body').mouseenter(function() {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        });
    }).mouseleave(function(e) {
        var pageX = e.pageX || e.clientX,
            pageY = e.pageY || e.clientY;

        if (pageX <= 0 || pageY <= 0) {
            start();
        }
        else
            clearTimeout(timer);
    });

    function refresh() {
        window.location.reload(true);
    });
</script>
```

*(This code was partially taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17714300/2593839)*

Comment: Oh God, you're basically recreating the horrible `meta refresh` tag.

Comment: not really, I'm basically refreshing a full screen iFrame based on user activity and more specifically a mouseenter/mousleave event. A meta refresh tag would not work for my specific needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should work :

```
function refresh() {
   window.location.reload(true);
}

var timer;
function start() {
  timer = setTimeout(function(){refresh()}, 5000);
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  start();

  jQuery('body').mouseenter(function() {
     clearTimeout(timer);
  }).mouseleave(function(e) {
     var pageX = e.pageX || e.clientX,
         pageY = e.pageY || e.clientY;

      if(pageX <= 0 || pageY <= 0) {
        start();
      }else {
        clearTimeout(timer);
      }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just take

```
clearInterval(timer);
```

not

```
clearTimeout(timer);
```

Comment: Well, it would be better to change the `setInterval()` call to use `setTimeout()`, as the function can run at most once

Comment: This would have worked as well, sorry I don't have enough reputation points to vote up!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
var mytimeout;
$('.box').on('mouseenter', function() {
  if(mytimeout) {
    clearTimeout(mytimeout);
  }

}).on('mouseleave', function() {
  mytimeout = setInterval(function() {
    console.log('tick');
  },1000);    
});
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uXrKG/

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
var mytimeout, i;
i = $('.box').text();

$('.box').on('mouseenter', function() {
    if(mytimeout) {

        clearInterval(mytimeout);
    }

}).on('mouseleave', function() {
    mytimeout = setInterval(function() {
        $('.box').text(i++);
    },1000);    
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uXrKG/1/)

Should use clearInterval not clearTimeout