# auto refresh for every 5 mins

Tags: javascript, coldfusion-10

this is my code

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript" src="JS/jQuery.js"></script>
    <script>
        function page_refresh(){
            document.getElementById('form2').action="project_file_dir.cfm"  
            document.getElementById('form2').submit();          
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body >
<cfoutput>
<cfset fileLocation ="\\squeaker\SiSystemsFile\WebServices\WebSites\Perforce\Bhargavi"> <!--- On mac set to /tmp --->
<cfdirectory
        action = "list"
        directory = "#fileLocation#"
        name = "files"
        filter="*.*">
<form  method="post" id="form2">
    <cfset f="#files.recordcount#">  
    <cfset mydatetime=now()>
    <cfset a=TimeFormat(MyDateTime,'hh:mm:ss tt')>
      Total File in <b> #fileLocation# </b> Count is <b> #f# </b> #TimeFormat(MyDateTime,'hh:mm tt')#
       <input type="button" name="Refresh" value="refresh" onclick="page_refresh()"><br>
       <b>Next Run</b>
      <cfset b=TimeFormat(DateAdd('n', +5, MyDateTime),'hh:mm:ss tt')>
       #TimeFormat(DateAdd('n', +5, MyDateTime),'hh:mm tt')#
    </cfoutput>

<cfset a= Minute(Now())>
<cfset b=a%5 >  
<cfoutput>#b#</cfoutput>
<!--- <cfinclude template="page_move_2.cfm"> --->
<cfloop condition="b gt 0">
        <cfoutput>inside loop</cfoutput>
    <cfset Sleep(6000)>

    <cfset b = b - 1 >

</cfloop>
<cfoutput>hi</cfoutput>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

i need to refresh the page for every 5 mins . how to do this . i used sleep() function but ui itself loaded after that sleep() is executed . this me how to reload the page for every 5 mins

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644027/auto-reload-web-page

Answer (score 146):

Refresh document every 300 seconds:

Using HTML Meta tag, add this inside the `<head>` tag of the page:

```html
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300">
```

Using Script:

```js
setInterval(function() {
    window.location.reload();
}, 300_000); // in ms
```

Comment: The interval callback only runs once since the reloading stops any scripts from running. setTimeout would achieve the same thing.

Comment: current code works in normal and ignores post variables. can we do this with post variables?

Answer (score 20):

> Page should be refresh auto using meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="60">
```

> content value in seconds.after one minute page should be refresh

Comment: Honestly this is the simplest answer out there, and doesn't require any javascript

Comment: This is the best answer. Is it blocking in any way? It's not js but how the html page counts the content="second"?

Comment: In HTML and XHTML, one can use the meta element with the value of the http-equiv attribute set to "Refresh" and the value of the content attribute set to "0" (meaning zero seconds), followed by the URI that the browser should request. It is important that the time-out is set to zero, to avoid that content is displayed before the new page is loaded. The page containing the redirect code should only contain information related to the redirect.

Comment: This is not restoring the scroll position

Answer (score 15):

Install an interval:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    setInterval(page_refresh, 5*60000); //NOTE: period is passed in milliseconds
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Auto reload with target of your choice. In this case target is `_self` set to every 5 minutes.

*300000 milliseconds = 300 seconds = 5 minutes*

as *60000 milliseconds = 60 seconds = 1 minute*.

**This is how you do it:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function load()
{
setTimeout("window.open('http://YourPage.com', '_self');", 300000);
}
</script>
<body onload="load()">
```

**Or this if it is the same page to reload itself:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function load()
{
setTimeout("window.open(self.location, '_self');", 300000);
}
</script>
<body onload="load()">
```