# How do I refresh my html page every 2 mins?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

I am currently using an html page for a webview within my iOS and Android apps. I don't want to update the native code and was wondering if I could just refresh the homepage which is index.html every 2 mins? Is it possible?

Comment: `setInterval(function() { window.location.reload() }, 120000);`

Comment: Did you even google your question? I copypastad your title into google and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19807665/auto-refresh-for-every-5-mins) was the 2nd result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="120">
```

---

> The `<meta http-equiv="refresh">` tag causes a web page to refresh
> automatically after a specified amount of time. Users generally don't
> expect automatic refreshes, so they can be disorienting. Refreshing
> also moves focus to the top of the page, which may frustrate or
> confuse users, particularly those who rely on screen readers or other
> assistive technologies.

- https://web.dev/meta-refresh/
- [Meta equiv refresh](https://www.metatags.org/all-meta-tags-overview/meta-equiv-refresh/)

Comment: can i add 2 meta tags? or do i need to add it to my meta tag?

Comment: You can add many meta tags as you want as long as they're valid

Comment: Refreshing with meta tags is fine for regular websites. But will not work on a lot of TVs using the default television browser. If your use is to have the page displayed on a television you should use the JavaScript way:

setInterval(function() {
    window.location.reload();
}, 120000);

Answer (score 5):

You can try to use like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="120">
```

or you can use `setInterval` like this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    window.location.reload();
}, 120000);
```

Comment: how do i setinterval? can you explain with a chunk of my code? I have no idea how js-html code works?

Comment: [Documentation is helpful](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload)

Comment: setInterval has no meaning in this context, since the page is refreshed, the timer will only ever be called once...

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
  setTimeout(function(){
       window.location.reload(1);
    }, 120000);
```

**EDIT**
Put this in head

```
<script>
      setTimeout(function(){
           window.location.reload(1);
        }, 120000);
</script>
```

**EDIT**

to attach this function only when page is ready use this

```
<script>
     $('document').ready(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
           window.location.reload(1);
        }, 120000);
     });
</script>
```

Comment: can you explain with a chunk of my code? i have no idea where to place it?

Comment: @vasilenicusor kudos for the parameter of the reload function. I did't know it was that easy to avoid the cache.

Comment: from http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp , by default, the reload() method reloads the page from the cache, but you can force it to reload the page from the server by setting the forceGet parameter to true: location.reload(true).

Answer (score 0):

You can Put meta tag before html start
e.g.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="120">
  <html> 
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">    
        <title>Mart</title>
```