# How do I auto refresh HTML page every hour?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to refresh an HTML page every hour automatically in the background. I was thinking about using PHP but I'm not sure what if that's possible.

This is all the I have:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3600" >
```

But this doesn't refresh automatically in the background. How can I do this? If this is possible in PHP and a cron job please let me know (with code preferably). Thank you.

Comment: _"automatically in the background"_ ? What do you mean by that ?

Comment: @Rayon automatically as in completely automatically. I just want to have to set it up and everyday it should refresh the HTML page every hour.

Comment: So basically your html page is cached somewhere and you want to set a new page every hour ?

Comment: You tagged the question with cron; So perhaps use it

Answer (score 5):

You can use javascript setInterval();

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){ reload_page(); },60*60000);
 });

 function reload_page()
 {
    window.location.reload(true);
 }
</script>
```

Comment: `setTimeout` will work just as good because the whole page is reloaded anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<?php
    $page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
     $sec = "3600";
?>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?php echo $sec?>;URL='<?php echo $page?>'">
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19807718/6390490

Refresh document every 300 seconds using HTML Meta tag

EDIT: for background you have to use ajax something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/25446696/6390490

```
function loadlink(){
   $('#links').load('test.php',function () {
     $(this).unwrap();
});
}

 loadlink(); // This will run on page load
 setInterval(function(){
 loadlink() // this will run after every 5 seconds
}, 5000);
```

for server side refreshing use

```
 header("Refresh: 300;url='http://thepage.com/example'");//set time here as per your need
```

Comment: but doesn't the website have to open for this to work?

Comment: for server side auto refreshing you can use header("Refresh: 300;url='http://thepage.com/example'");

Comment: alright, so if I use that  (the server side PHP) and try to run it as a cron job will it work?

Comment: its working for me why don't u try and test it and can tell your experience in comments

Comment: I used tried using the server side script (I only used that) and ran it as a cron job (in Godaddy). It didn't work. Do I have to use both the server side and client side code together? Thanks for your help. @smarttechy

Comment: Hi, I am using Server Side Scripting for my callback notification sections                                                                        header("Refresh:10;url='https://domain/admin/callback.php'");                                                                                                      but the all the pages are redirecting to same page which I have given in URL section. Please help me out. Thank you.