# Flask, Javascript : Refresh with SQL query

Tags: python, pandas, flask, jinja2

I want to update my template querying every 5 second but I get the same value for every case. How do I keep refreshing and retrieve the values per each 5 second?
I want to implement monitoring script querying my database every 5 second.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    while True:
      conn = MySQLdb.connect(host=host,
                             user=username,
                             passwd=password,
                             db=database,
                             port=port)
      df = sqlio.read_sql(qry1, conn)
      value = df['id'][0]
      print value
      conn.close()
      time.sleep(5)
      return render_template('index.html', thev=value)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(
        port=8001,
        host='0.0.0.0'
    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `while True` part of your code doesn't do anything - when a request is made, the template will be rendered once and the function exits.

You'll need to do something on the client side to refresh the data.  This could be as a simple as an [auto-refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644027/auto-reload-web-page-if-there-is-no-recent-activity), or you could do something in javascript to asynchronously update the data without refreshing the page (lots of examples online, [here's](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xv-ajax) the section from the Flask mega tutorial)

Comment: Does it mean that `index()` gets to be called every second without `while`?

Comment: No, `index()` is called once when the client makes a request to the server (i.e. when you open the page in a browser)