# How to clear button clicks when using javascript to refresh my html page?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, page-refresh

I'm using the java script from [How to automatically reload a page after a given period of inactivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644027/how-to-automatically-reload-a-page-after-a-given-period-of-inactivity) to refresh my html page every 30 seconds, and it works great. The page contains a form, some buttons and some text fields.The form also contains a statuslist that is updated when the page is refreshed. When clicking on a button will the corresponding value be sent back to the server. The problem is that once I have clicked a button once, it is repeated every 30 second due to the refresh from the javascript.
How to remove the button click after the first time?
I want to keep the values in the text fields.

Comment: Added info about the statuslist, that is the reason for automatic reload of the page

Comment: are you having a handler defined ? are you adding any event listener to the button ?

Comment: @ Nielarshi: Yes, I have an event listener for the button, but it seams like once the form is submitted, the values remains when doing a refresh. I have tested to change some of the text fields and they are restored by the  refresh :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, but not by using javascript.
I added another html page, where I go to when submitting the form.
Here I extract the data from the textfields (and call some php).
Then I goes back to the first page usining the php header command, with the data attached but not the buttons.
I still uses the javascript on the first page to update the statuslist, but don't get any duplicate button clicks due to the refresh.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a function attached to your button like

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

then add this line to that function

```
clickFlag = true
```

otherwise add this to your button tag

```
<button onclick="clickFlag = true">Click me</button>
```

and change your refresh function as following

```
 var time = new Date().getTime();
 $(document.body).bind("mousemove keypress", function(e) {
     time = new Date().getTime();
 });

 function refresh() {
     if(new Date().getTime() - time >= 30000 && clickFlag) 
         window.location.reload(true);
     else 
         setTimeout(refresh, 10000);
 }

 setTimeout(refresh, 10000);
```

Comment: The values in the text field will not remain when using reset. The refresh will only be done when clicking a button with the solution above, not every 30 second. Isn't there a way to clear just some values?

Comment: i've edited my answer, the page will only refresh if 30 seconds have passed without any activity and button hasn't been clicked.

Comment: Isn't a keypress still needed for the page to reload as the clickFlag==true still is there ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use meta tags .
These attributes HTTP-EQUIV,content are needed.
Ex: http://website/login">

Comment: I don't understand how this would help here?