# Auto Link after idle on several times

Tags: url, autolink

I've read a thread and it's help me a bit, https://stackoverflow.com/a/4644315/4910669.

```
<script>
 var time = new Date().getTime();
 $(document.body).bind("mousemove keypress", function(e) {
     time = new Date().getTime();
 });

 function refresh() {
     if(new Date().getTime() - time >= 60000) 
         window.location.reload(true);
     else 
         setTimeout(refresh, 10000);
 }

 setTimeout(refresh, 10000);
```

But anyone can help me if I need to linked or href it to my homepage, ex :

```
<?php echo base_url(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the location you need to refresh in the `JS`:

Instead of this:

`window.location.reload(true);`

Change it to:

`window.location.assign(<?php echo base_url(); ?> /*or any URL*/);`