# Timer stops working on second webpage tab

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer

I have an `Timer` on my webpage and for testing I filled its `onTick` event with an `Respose.Redirect`.

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate> 
            <asp:Timer ID="tiUpdater" runat="server" OnTick="GetTime" Interval="1000" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>


    protected void GetTime(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~");
    }
```

I discovered that if I have my page open in a second tab, both pages refresh each second but after I click in one tab any button, the timer on the second page stops refreshing.

Do you have an explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: The information in this question is not enough to give an answer, try pasting the entire code behind if you can. There is probably something "static" going on.

Answer (score 0):

Give more info pls, past the entire code behind if you can.

I would suggest you try the Javascript nonetheless, there is no need for the server to recieve a call just to refresh the page.

See this for the JS solution: [How to automatically reload a page after a given period of inactivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644027/how-to-automatically-reload-a-page-after-a-given-period-of-inactivity)

In case you are targeting an environment where JS cannot be enabled, try the meta tag way:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=http://www.yourdomain.com/yoursite.html">
```

5 is seconds here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your problem but maybe try to set propertie `AutoReset` to `true`