# Auto refresh after 5 min

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the implantation for auto refresh on my project which is chat bot. When the chat page is open and a conversation is loaded, I should periodically refresh the conversation entries list. 
By default, every 5 seconds.

1. If there are no additional conversation entries on a refresh, we should increment the wait time by 5 seconds, up to a maximum of 120 seconds.
2. If there are additional conversation entries on a refresh, we should reset the wait time to 5 seconds.

Comment: What have you tried? Please show us your code...

Comment: i was doing something like this it didn't work <script type="text/javascript">
function load()
{
setTimeout("window.open(self.location, '_self');", 300000);
}
</script>
<body onload="load()">

Comment: Don't use AJAX polling for chat systems. It is basically DDOSing your own server. Use WebSockets.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644027/how-to-automatically-reload-a-page-after-a-given-period-of-inactivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var delayTime = 5000;

```
    function refresh() {
        if(chatid.length > 0) {
        ChatService.getChatDetailsById(chatid)
            .then(function (result) {
                if (result.Data.Messages.length > $scope.chatDetails.Messages.length) {
                    getChatDetails(chatid)
                    delayTime = 5000;
                } else {
                    increseDelay();
                }
                timeout();
            });
            function increseDelay() {
                if (delayTime !== 120000)
                    delayTime += 5000;
            }
        }
    }
    function timeout() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            refresh();
        }, delayTime);
    };
    timeout();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebSocket for your chat bot. you see https://www.html5rocks.com/es/tutorials/websockets/basics/

Comment: thanks for the response

Comment: i was looking at signal r

Comment: ?¿?¿ I don't understand that you search, you need a server.