# Auto loading the web page

Tags: automation, load

I need to load the web page each 5 minutes, automatically. 
The web page will have (maybe) new text, and I need to load it without user intervention.
How to do it?

Comment: writing code would be a good start.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Robust auto-refresh web page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729959/robust-auto-refresh-web-page)

Comment: Good link, thanks; it makes me thinking in a new way of doing what I want - I'm posting a new question.

Comment: Do you think the answer from member Reboot in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729959/robust-auto-refresh-web-page could be changed to refresh the page content, each 5 minutes, for 6 (no more, no less) times?

Answer (score 1):

You could just use this meta tag inside the `<head> </head>` tags of the page you want to reload.

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="300">
```

This will reload the page every 300 seconds.

HIH

Comment: Glad it helped. I think you can mark this as accepted if it was what you were looking for. @jah

Comment: Sorry, There's no button *accept* to be clicked on. I guess, this is due to low *reputation* points I got. I'm even not allowed to post another question while  a timeout doesn't occur.

Comment: Do you think the answer from member Reboot in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729959/robust-auto-refresh-web-page could be changed to refresh the page content, each 5 minutes, for 6 (no more, no less) times?