# Auto loading a web page for a certain (and fixed) number of times

Tags: automation, load, page-refresh

I need to load a web page and refresh it, automatically, each 5 minutes. It should be refreshed 6 times (30 minutes) and no more. In another question I made, I got a link ( [Robust auto-refresh web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729959/robust-auto-refresh-web-page) ) where a reply from member Reboot has a code I think could be changed to be used as I need. Is it possible to change that code in order to re-load the web page, automatically, for a fixed number of times? If so, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This uses `sessionStorage` to save the number of reloads which [should work in IE8+](http://caniuse.com/namevalue-storage) except for Opera Mini.  If this is a problem, set cookies instead (but then the client has to accept cookies).

Tweak `maxReloads` and `pollIntervalSecs` to your liking.

```
<script>
var pollIntervalId;
var pollIntervalSecs = 6;
var maxReloads = 3;
var doReload = function(){
    var reloads = sessionStorage.getItem("reloads");
    if (!reloads) sessionStorage.setItem("reloads", 0);
    reloads++;
    if(reloads > maxReloads) {
        window.clearInterval(pollIntervalId);
    } else {
        sessionStorage.setItem("reloads", reloads);
        document.location.reload(true);
    }
}
pollIntervalId = setInterval(doReload, pollIntervalSecs * 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this will do.

Comment: I tried to vote up, but it seems I don't have enough ''reputation'' points.